# I tried to fetch my database content and display using Ajax but I see this error

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

ERROR:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
> responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
> "accept" headers.

Here is my Ajax code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*  function new_element(){ */
  
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search").click(function(){
    console.log("fetched list");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcJdbcTemplate/listContact",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : 'json',
        /* contentType : "application/json", */
        accept : "application/json",
        
        success : function(data) {
            alert(this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
          display(data);
      },
      error : function(e) {
          console.log("ERROR: ", e);
          display(e);
      }
    
    });
    });
});
function display(data) {
    console.log("inside func list");
    var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4>&lt;pre&gt;"

            + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "&lt;/pre&gt;";
    $('#feedback').html(json);
}

</script>
```

The controller class

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/listContact", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public AjaxResponseBody listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
        System.out.println("listContact");
        List<Contactdup> listContdup = new ArrayList<Contactdup>();
        Contactdup contactdup = null ;
        AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();
      
        for(Contact contact:listContact) {
            contactdup = new Contactdup();
            contactdup.setFname(contact.getFname());
            System.out.println("inside for");
            System.out.println(contact.getFname());
            listContdup.add(contactdup);    
        }
        result.setResult(listContdup);
        result.setCode("200");
        result.setMsg("");
    return result;
    
}
```

AjaxResponseBody:

```
package ajaxrespose;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

import net.codejava.spring.model.Contactdup;
import net.codejava.spring.model.Views;



public class AjaxResponseBody {
    
    public List<Contactdup> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Contactdup> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    String msg;
    
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    String code;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    List<Contactdup> result;
}
```

Comment: Your ajax `accept : "application/json"` and your Java code produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`. which is a string equivalent of MediaTypeAPPLICATION_JSON (application/json). Keep java to method to produce `MediaTypeAPPLICATION_JSON`

Comment: when I tried to change (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)Type mismatch: cannot convert from MediaType to String[] I get this error

Comment: Can you post the `AjaxResponseBody` class and further what is the type of `result.setResult`?

Comment: posted AjaxResponseBody

Comment: result.setResult type is array List

Comment: Got it. Do one thing, just remove the `accept : "application/json"` from the ajax call and also change the java method to remove `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`

Comment: still not working removed both (accept : "application/json"and also MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: Can you hit the same URL via Browser or via `curl -s -I http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcJdbcTemplate/listContact` ? I was able to get this working with a simple spring-boot `AjaxResponseBody` or even if I use `ResponseEntity` as a return type

Comment: Thanks for the inputs my problem got solved .Now I am able to get the Ajax call and display the data in console , here is the code that I have altered produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {"application/json"}) in controller

Answer (score 0):

The route you are calling is probably not returning content-type "application/json".

Comment: helped me to find the way for getting Ajax call thanks